# How to use PNG mask in segmentation object detection with Tensorflow

Tags: windows, tensorflow, mask, object-detection

I am using tutorial from [here](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10).

I use mask_rcnn_inception_v2 detection model with my own dataset. I want to add PNG mask, i use some applications to do it. but I wonder how i put this data to be used in detection. I see the mention anywhere.

1. How to implement the PNG mask in object detection ? (where i put it, how to use it)
2. Do you know how to launch the evaluation and training in same time on tensorboard i see it is possible.
3. generally where i can ask all Tensorflow general question as configuration file explanations

On Github Tensorflow it is specified we have to ask question here because not a Tensorflow issue and great community here with some great guys!

Comment: I use the data_tools/pet_create_tfrecord.py and faces_only to False, i made this tree : mask/images /mask/test_images mask/annotations/xmls and mask/annotations/masks. any idea ?

Comment: no one could answer  ?no one manage to make mask rcnn dataset pet working ?

Comment: sometimes i am surprised from community reaction, instead of fix the ... after a sentence or replace a word by another, please make something useful and answer to the question to win some points. unbelievable ! Thank you for fixing punctuation ! it is very important ! great !

Comment: Not everyone can provide a helpful answer: someone gives contribution by improving the question syntax. Improving it gives you the opportunity to reach more people, and therefore it increases the probability that your answer can be found (or searched).

Comment: yes i agree, but improving question with useless modifications i am not agree, it is done to win some points easily for example  (where i put it, how to use it) intead of  (where i put it, how to use it...) (... means there is not only 2 questions ) do you think it is useful ? .bref thank you all we keep on going i love U all -)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to guy on github he points a missing configuration in pipeline.config

number_of_stages: 3

and it changes all the result i can see the mask now. youpi !

Answer (score 0):

For any further information, there's a good explanation here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/instance_segmentation.md

It explains how to prepare you masks and what to modify.

Comment: i followed all documentations possible but not working, i don't know if i make mask outline right